# UILabel does get roundedCorners

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have extended the UIView class and added a property for cornerRadius. The property does set to desired value. I have made two custom classes one derives from UITextField and another from UILabel. UITextField gets rounded corners but UILabel does not.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

```
@IBDesignable
public class BLabel: UILabel {


public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    clipsToBounds = true

}


required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }
}

extension UIView {
@IBInspectable
var cornerRadius : CGFloat {
    get {return layer.cornerRadius}
    set {layer.cornerRadius = newValue}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank @rmaddy for help. I am writing this for the benefit for all. The code given by rmaddy works. But, after testing it I figured out that it is not required. Just setting layer.masksToBounds = true in UIView extension cornerRadius setter method does the trick. So the entire problem was solved by just this one line of code.

So the final code looks like this and it works:

```
@IBDesignable
public class BTextField: UITextField {


    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)


    }
}


@IBDesignable
public class BLabel: UILabel {


    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }


}



extension UIView {
     @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius : CGFloat {
        get {return layer.cornerRadius}
        set {layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        layer.masksToBounds = true}
    }

}
```

I hope it helps others also.

Answer (score 2):

In your `BLabel` class you access the `cornerRadius` property of your `UIView` extension in the `init` method. This is before you have any chance to set a specific corner radius value so it will be 0.

There's no point to the line `layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius` in the `init` method of `BLabel`. Simply create the `BLabel` instance and then set its `cornerRadius` property.

```
let label = BLabel(frame: someFrame)
label.cornerRadius = 5
```

Comment: actually the code in init of BLabel is redundant after i extended UIView. I just forgot to comment that. The puzzling part here is that Subclass of UITextField gets rounded corners and BLabel (which is a subclass of UILabel) does not get rounded corners.

Comment: Update your question to show how you create and setup the label and how you create and setup the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Are you *sure* your `UITextField` is responding to `cornerRadius`? Or are you maybe just seeing the normal rounded corners?

Try changing your `BLabel` to this - it will make sure the initializations are being called properly:

```
@IBDesignable
public class BLabel: UILabel {


    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    public override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        commonInit()
    }

    public override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {

        // As noted by "rmaddy" ---
        // setting .cornerRadius here does nothing, as it is always equal to Zero
        // the UIView extension will handle it
        //layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius

        layer.masksToBounds = true
        clipsToBounds = true

        // the following just makes it easy to confirm
        // that this code is being executed
        backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        textColor = UIColor.yellow
        textAlignment = .center
    }

}
```

Comment: It's pointless to have `layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius` in `commonInit` because it will always be 0 at this point.

Comment: @rmaddy - he is using it along with the `UIView @IBInspectable` extension. Works well (in my quick test).

Comment: To clarify my point, it won't be useful when called via `init(frame:)` or `init(coder:)`.

Comment: @rmaddy - you are absolutely correct - my bad. Answer has been updated. Thx

Comment: @rmaddy: your code worked well. I tested it by eliminating each override and found that prepareForInterfaceBuilder() was doing the trick. But then i realised that i should try setting     layer.masksToBounds = true in UIView extension and it worked like a charm. i removed all other methods. Just for benefit of all setting     layer.masksToBounds = true in UIView extension solves the problem. Thank you very much rmaddy for your help.